# Django : CSRF verification failed even after adding {% csrf_token %}

Tags: python, django

**views.py:**

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', {})

def photos(request, artist):
    if not artist:
        return render_to_response('photos.html', {'error' : 'no artist supplied'})
    photos = get_photos_for_artist(artist)
    if not photos:
        logging.error('Issue while getting photos for artist')
        return render_to_response('photos.html', {'error': 'no matching artist found'})
    return render_to_response('photos.html', {'photos': photos})
```

**Index.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>find artist photos </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block error %} {% endblock %}
        <form action="/photos" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="artist">Artist : </label>
            <input type="text" name="artist">
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**photos.html:**

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block error %}
    {% if error %}
        <p> {{ error}} </p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% if photos %}
        {% for photo in photos %}
            {{ photo }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock%}
```

**url.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'', index),
    (r'^time/$', current_datetime),
    (r'^photos/(\w+)$', photos)
)
```

I even tried by adding `{% csrf_token %}`, but no luck

Thank you

**UPDATE**
I see these in the logs

```
UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
  warnings.warn("A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.")
```

This came after adding **context_instance=RequestContext(request)** **to render_to_response()**

Answer (score 9):

add `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` to every view that you will use a form inside it:

```
return render_to_response('index.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )


return render_to_response('photos.html', {'photos': photos}, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

Comment: ...or if you use Django 1.3, you can use a shorter version of this:
`render(request, 'index.html', {})`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Answer (score 5):

Supposing you are using a fairly recent version of Django (1.3/1.4/dev) you should follow these steps :

- In `settings.py`, Add the middleware `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` to the 
  `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` list.
- In your template, use the `{% crsf_token %}` in the form.
- In your view, ensure that the `django.core.context_processors.csrf` context processor is used either by :

  - use `RequestContext` from `django.template`
  - directly import the csrf processor from `from django.core.context_processors`

### Examples

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def my_view(request):
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

or

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def my_view(request):
    c = {csrf(request)}
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', c)
```

### References

- [csrf in Django 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/) or [csrf in Django 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/)
- [RequestContext in Django 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) or RequestContext in Django 1.4

(exhaustive post for posterity and future viewers)

Answer (score 3):

A number of things to troubleshoot here:

- Please load your "index" page in a web browser, do "View Source", and check if the `{% csrf_token %}` is being expanded.  It should be replaced with an `<input>` tag.  If that's not happening, then you have problems with your index page.  If it is being replaced correctly, then you have problems with your photos page.
- The POST URL in `index.html` doesn't match any of the patterns in `urls.py`.  Your `urls.py` seems to expect the search term to be part of the URL, but it's not - you're sending it as a HTTP POST parameter.  You need to access it via `request.POST`.

Comment: Good points. It is usually better to do searches with a GET instead of a POST method as they can then be bookmarked. So I would suggest changing the template, over changing the view. One or the other does need to be changed.

Comment: Actually , this is the Ultimate solution! I ran across a lot of articles mentioning this problem, but only this one point out the truth. Please render the index page with Requestcontext as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check in the settings, if you have this middleware:

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Comment: and the context processor 'django.core.context_processors.csrf'?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to explicitly pass in a RequestContext instance when you use render_to_response in order to get the CSRF values for that template tag.

http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2008/may/10/getting-requestcontext-your-templates/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the @csrf_protect decorator:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

@csrf_protect
def photos(request,artist):
    if not artist:
        return render_to_response('photos.html', {'error' : 'no artist supplied'})
    photos = get_photos_for_artist(artist)
    if not photos:
        logging.error('Issue while getting photos for artist')
        return render_to_response('photos.html', {'error': 'no matching artist found'})
    return render_to_response('photos.html', {'photos': photos})
```

Comment: Tried that, but it in that case doesn't seem to be calling photos function, logs say [06/Dec/2011 18:08:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 403
[06/Dec/2011 18:08:08] "POST /photos HTTP/1.1" 200 403

Comment: I guess you've seen this: "By default, a '403 Forbidden' response is sent to the user if an incoming request fails the checks performed by CsrfViewMiddleware. This should usually only be seen when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when, due to a programming error, the CSRF token has not been included with a POST form." from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/.

It seems the CSRF-token is not properly transmitted somehow.

Comment: If you add csrf_protect to the index view?

Comment: I added @csrf_protect in both index and photos, but no luck! I am sure its programming error, but not sure where

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

{% csrf_token %}
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.

In views.py:

**from django.template import RequestContext**

...

...

...

return render_to_response("home.html", {}, **context_instance=RequestContext(request)**)

Comment: Not sure how this answer adds something hasn't already been covered by already posted answers?