# django csrf_token not printing hidden input field

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-csrf

my `views.py` :

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.http import *
from django.template import *
from django.shortcuts import *
# Create your views here.
@csrf_protect
def homepage(request):
        return render_to_response('index.html', {'files':os.listdir('/home/username/public_html/posters') })
@csrf_protect
def upload(request):
        return render_to_response('list.html', )
```

in my template `index.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> All uploaded posters: </h1>
<form action='/posters/upload' method= 'POST'>{%csrf_token%}
<input type='file' name= 'uploadfile'>Upload new poster <input type="submit" value = "Upload">
</form>
{%for file in files %}
<a href = 'http://servername/~username/posters/{{file}}'>{{file}}</a> <br />
{%endfor%}
</body>
</html>
```

so when I open the homepage in browser and see the source code and there's no csrf token!

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> All uploaded posters: </h1>
<form action='/posters/upload' method= 'POST'>
<input type='file' name= 'uploadfile'>Upload new poster <input type="submit" value = "Upload">
</form>

<a href= ......
```

What did I miss?

***UPDATE***: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408545/django-csrf-verification-failed-even-after-adding-csrf-token) helped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use RequestContext in order to use CSRF middleware:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

# In your view:
return render_to_response('index.html'
    {'files':os.listdir('/home/username/public_html/posters') },
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

BTW: Use of `csrf_protect` decorator is not recommended, since if you forget to use it, you will have a security hole.

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me nuts. Glad it was something simple.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are on 1.3 (which you should be), the [render](http://django.me/render) shortcut offers a more compact way of doing it:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def some_view(request):
    return render(request, 'template.html', context_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the snippet from django document.

The decorator method
Rather than adding CsrfViewMiddleware as a blanket protection, you can use the csrf_protect decorator, which has exactly the same functionality, on particular views that need the protection. **It must be used both on views that insert the CSRF token in the output, and on those that accept the POST form data.** (These are often the same view function, but not always). It is used like this:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.template import RequestContext

@csrf_protect
def my_view(request):
    c = {}
    # ...
    return render_to_response("a_template.html", c,
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Use of the decorator is not recommended by itself**, since if you forget to use it, you will have a security hole. The 'belt and braces' strategy of using both is fine, and will incur minimal overhead.